# When to use numberOfSections or numberOfRowsInSection ? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

**Why ?**
 I don't know why the output gave me 3 sections only. I am very confused about numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection.

**What I don't know:**

Why the output returns 3 sections only?

**What I know:**

I saw a few post on StackOverFlow, they said **Sections** are like a group, and **Rows** are like the cells in the sections. But I still feel a little confused.

Comment: It looks like you have 1 section with 11 rows

Comment: Keep simple thing in mind, sections are something like your groups and rows are the records of your groups. In simple case of table view we uses default section number(i.e 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int // Default is 1 if not implemented` and  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` is `UITableViews` Data Source method, `numberOfSections` is not required when you want only the same type of repeated list in your TableView, Like: suppose you want to show below in your tableview

1

2

3

4

..

in that case you will be required `numberOfRowsInSection` `return 4` here your table will return 4 cells, if you not give `numberOfSections` this method it will be 1 by default and you code will work without having this method in your class.

But Suppose you need to show in your tableview that 
1
2
3
4
A
B
C
D
It can be achieved by entering these data in an Array as string and print that in `cellForAt`.

But to make more it organige, what you can do here for better view to the user is to use section. Like

**Number**

1

2

3

4

**Alphabet**

A

B

C

D

Here You have to use `numberOfSections` and it should return 2, one for Number and second for Alphabet. and 1,2,3,4 and A,B,C,D are the rows under their section Number and Alphabet.
I hope You got it, else comment below I'll try again to make you understand.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know why Section: 1 Rows: 11 Section: 1 Rows: 11 Section: 1 Rows: 11 come out. I did not set any specific sections like ( **Number** / **Alphabets** )

Comment: **MY Code:**  `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                 if let sections = controllerOut.sections {
            print("Section: \(sections.count)")
            return sections.count
        }
        return 0
    }`

Comment: Here, What is your controllerOut ? it must be an class object and sections may be an Array of that class.! I guess..

Comment: `var controllerOut: NSFetchedResultsController<Item>!`

Comment: is for fetch the Item

Comment: Yes, then controllerOut is an object of NSFetchedResultsController class which is contain another array object namely sections, when your class get the value of any section it store it in  this sections variable like Number, Alphabet from my given Answer, If there is no Alphabet then your section is Number Only right ? that's why you get 1 for section. Did you get it?

Comment: **item.title** = "Mac Apple"
        **item.price** = 9810
        **item.detail** = "I love this Macbook because it has a lot of ports."

Comment: so the **bold** text is my sections ?

Comment: **Thank you** for your explanation. I finally got it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a kind of grouping but don't mix it up with the *grouped* appearance of the table view.

Simple example: Look at the icon of the Contacts.app

[image]

The letters are the sections, the containing contacts are the rows in the section.

Your output reveals you have 1 section with 11 rows.

Comment: but I saw 3 sections there. Why ?

Comment: Section: 1
Rows: 11
Section: 1
Rows: 11
Section: 1
Rows: 11

Comment: No, `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are called three times and you got three times the same information. If you had three sections you wold get `Section: 3`

Comment: **Thank you** for your explanation. I finally got it.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` presents its data in a two-level hierarchy: Sections and Rows. 
A section is exactly that: a way to group one or more rows that have something in common (what that means, will depend on the particular data displayed).

For example, assume your data rows consist of **home appliances**, and you want to group them according to **in which room** they are placed:

```
- Kitchen
  - microwave
  - fridge
  - toaster

- Bedroom
  - computer
  - lamp
```

Here, you have **two sections** (named `Kitchen` and `Bedroom`), **and they have 3 rows and 2 rows respectively**.

Or maybe you have a list of people grouped by nationality. Or cities grouped by state. How you use this two-level hierarchy, is up to you and what makes more sense for **your** data model.

Of course, you can always flatten the hierarchy by having only one section that contains all rows. This is the default behaviour if you don't implement or override the method `numberOfSections(inTableView:)`.

Comment: **Thank you** for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can explain this better than the explanation you already found. 
Sections are groups of rows, the rows are elements of a section.

An object that can describe you visually a multiple section set of data could be:

`let multipleSection = [["section1-row1", "section1-row2", "section1-row3"], ["section2-row1", "section2-row2", "section2-row3"]]`

This array contains other arrays: each one of that subarrays are SECTIONS.

The content of each section are the ROWS that belong to that section.

I hope it helps and that I got it right what was confusing you.

Comment: I don't know why the output has 3 **sections** I did not set any sections to the tableView.

Comment: why my output display                                                                                                                                                                                                **Section:** 1
       Rows: 11
**Section:** 1
       Rows: 11
**Section:** 1
       Rows: 11